# slow Openlayers with 270000 points

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, postgresql, drupal, cartaro

I have 270 000 points on a map.
If you zoom out, the site hangs for a very long time and sometime the page just crash.

I use Cartaro with Drupal.
https://www.drupal.org/project/cartaro
Cartaro is a Drupal module, tha uses PostGis, GeoServer (drupal), GeoWebCache and Openlayers (for Drupal). Database is postgresql. In Ol i used Geoserver WMS for Layer.

This is my first attemt at all of the above, so im a very big noob. Hope the info provided is ok, or else, please ask again

Right now, i have the OL to zoom in automaticly on the user, so not so many points are loaded. I use bounding box, and the page loads instant. But the problem is, if the user zooms out a bit, the server dies or lag severly.

Im new to this, but stumbled over minscale and maxscale.
Could that be my solution ?
How and where do i insert minscale and maxscale ?

Comment: Welcome! Please provide information about how your data is stored. Database, shapefile, etc?

Comment: Hi

I use Cartaro module.

Cartaro uses PostGis, GeoServer, GeoWebCache and Openlayers. 
Database is postgresql.

In Ol i used Geoserver WFS for Layer.

Sorry for the missing info. This is my first attemt at all of the above, so im a very big noob. Hope the info provided is ok, or else, please ask again.

Comment: Cartaro is a Drupal Module, so OL is also the Drupal version.

Comment: just add the info in your original posting. You can edit it and add the above information in the question. This makes it easier for others to read the question/answer pair later :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to either restrict the zoom to a workable area or alternatively restrict the amount of painted features.

There's a *Zoom restrictions for non-base layers.* behavior which can be enabled in the map configuration. Maybe it's okay to only display features when the user zoomed close.

Alternatively, use the *Cluster Features* behavior to reduce the amount of painting by grouping features with close proximity. See http://demo.cartaro.org/admin/structure/openlayers/maps/list/swisstopo/edit for a similar case. Your layer needs to be delivered as WFS (raw features) as a prerequisite, though.

If you want to stick to WMS and have your map on all zoom levels, you should consider filtering the features to paint. A custom SLD can archive that but that's not a simple as the previously mentioned approaches.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot.
Selected WFS and turned cluster features on and made zoom restrictions to layer.